# Can someone offer a high-level explanation Win 10 Pro audio configuration?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, speakers

UPDATE: OK, I found the App Volume Device Settings Sound settings which answers some of my questions. I have played around with the behaviours, turned on/off connect/disconnect the Bluetooth speaker. I have plugged in my earbuds to the audio jack. Changed the default speaker between the three options listed below.

I guess the only remaining questions are:

1. Is there a shortcut one can place on the desktop/task bar to quickly change the default output?
2. it seems there are inconsistencies in behaviour (i.e. bugs) when I switch back and forth between the bluetooth speaker (that is turn the speaker, itself, on/off, and connect/disconnect the speaker in bluetooth settings) and the other output devices. I know that it was only in the last couple of months that Windows actually allowed permitted users to manually connect/disconnect a detected Bluetooth speaker. Perhaps they didn't expand their test suite sufficiently to make sure all use cases would cork correctly.

I just wish it worked in some predictable manner.

=====================================

Sorry to rant but I just can't figure out what the designers of Win 10 had in mind when they set up audio. If I had an idea of what they were thinking, I could likely help myself.

System - Lenovo 13s laptop with a 2nd screen connected by HDMI (which also has embedded speakers and which are recognized by Windows). I also have a bluetooth external speaker which I sometimes use, sometimes not. So, I have 3 speaker options and I see all three in various Windows audio setting windows. Everything beyond that is a jumbled mess.

For the most part, I want all audio output to go to, let's call it, a default device. Usually that will be the laptop speaker. When I have the Bluetooth speaker turned on, then - if I have "connect" set in Windows Bluetooth properties - I will want Windows to automatically switch over to the Bluetooth. When I Turn off or disconnect (in Bluetooth settings) the speaker, I want Windows to automatically revert to the laptop speaker. If I want to switch to the speaker in the external monitor (it is louder, for example, than the onboard laptop speaker, which is sometimes useful), I want to know the simplest way to direct all output there.

Confounding this is, apparently, the possibility of setting app-level overrides of the Windows configuration (?). iTunes, for example, is being directed to the laptop speaker and I can't get it to output to Bluetooth. If someone can direct me to where such overrides are configured, I would appreciate it.

Windows provides too many ways, it seems to me, to configure even the simplest things.

I appreciate any guidance that can be offered.

Ken

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to change where audio goes to is to left click the speaker icon.

Above the volume control slider will be the name of the current playback (output) device.

You can click that name to select a different device.

When one device is disconnected it should fall back to the previously selected one.

If you chose a device that is subsequently disconnected then it should be selected by default the next time it is reconnected.

To follow this setting applications should be set to use the "default audio device" or whatever equivalent the application names it.